# On SIM7600CE, with the command AT + CHTTPSOPSE why is there a socket creation error?

Tags: sockets, https, arduino-uno

My shield is the SIM7600CE.
I've been blocked for several days. I use the FONA_fruit for the SIM7000 and SIM7500, I read the AT command manual and it's the same for SIM7500/7600. I think it's too good for this electronic card.
When I right in manually the AT command, everything is good and my get is sending but when I use the function postData, I have the error code 13 = Create socket error.
The error after the CHTTPSSTART is normal because it's already started.

```
---> AT+CHTTPSSTART
<--- ERROR 
Waiting 1s to ensure connection...
---> AT+CHTTPSOPSE="dweet.io",443,2
<--- OK
<--- +CHTTPSOPSE:13
```

Manually, I right that and it's ok :

```
AT+CHTTPSSTART //For the first time
AT+CHTTPSOPSE="dweet.io",443,2
AT+CHTTPSSEND=56

GET /dweet/for/862649048570708?temp=24 HTTP/1.1
```

Sorry if I did some mistakes.
Thank's for your futur help.